# sum of values in one column as separate columns

Tags: google-bigquery, sum, case, multiple-columns

I have three columns in my table. `date`, `ad_id`, `action_type` and `value`. I want the values from `action_type` column to become separate columns with the associated SUM of the values from the column `value`. The data looks like this:

```
date      ad_id        action_type        value
7/11       1            post               2
7/11       1            post               1
7/11       1            click              100
7/11       2            post               4
7/11       2            click              20
7/11       2            click              3
```

The desired output is:

```
date      ad_id         post        click
7/11       1            3            100
7/11       2            4            23
```

I tried thee following, but I am clearly missing the `value` column in my query, can't find the right syntax to include it for the sums.

```
select 
    date,
    ad_id,
    sum(case when action_type = 'post' then 1 else 0 end) as post_,
    sum(case when action_type = 'click' then 1 else 0 end) as clicks
from `my_table`
group by 1,2
```

Comment: Change `then 1` to `then value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case if you really meant BigQuery (based on original tags)

```
select *
from `my_table`
pivot (sum(value) for action_type in ('post', 'click'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems correct except the summing value being used. Just use column value instead of 1 in your query.

```
select 
    date,
    ad_id,
    sum(case when action_type = 'post' then value else 0 end) as post_,
    sum(case when action_type = 'click' then value else 0 end) as clicks
from `my_table`
group by 1,2
```